# LZMA SDK iOS to show progress

Tags: ios, objective-c, lzma

If anyone has used the iOS wrapper for the LZMA SDK available at https://github.com/mdejong/lzmaSDK and have been able to tweak it in order to see the progress of unarchiving, please help.

I am going to use this SDK in iOS to extract a 16MB file, which uncompresses to a 150MB file, and this takes around 40seconds to complete. It would be good to have some kind of callback for showing the progress of uncompression.

Help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I looked at this issue quite a bit recently, and honestly the best you are going to be able to do is look for all the files in a specific tmp dir where decompression is going on and then count them and compare to a known size N. The problem with attempting to do this in the library is that it spans multiple runtimes and the callback idea makes the code a mess. Also, a callback would not help that much because of the way 7z compression works. To decode, one needs to build up the decompression dictionary before specific files can be decompressed, and that process of building up the dictionary takes a long time before the first file can even be written. So, if you put a "percent done" counter in your app showing how much was done, it would show 0% done for a long time, then jump to 50% and then 90 or 100 %. Basically, it would not be that useful even if it was implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You could try C++ port of the latest LZMA SDK(15.06) without described above limitations(C version). Memory allocations and IO read/write can be tuned in runtime, plus work with password encrypted archives, smoothed progress, Lzma & Lzma2 archive types etc.

GitHub: https://github.com/OlehKulykov/LzmaSDKObjC